# Labels, text area, and button not positioning properly

Tags: html, css, button, label, textarea

I'm trying to adjust my code to position the feedback label with the textarea along the right and the button at the bottom centered. I couldn't get them to align properly and was struggling with it for a while and need some help now:

HTML

```
 <div class = "formBkg">
<br></br>
<label class = "lbl">First Name: <b class = "red">*</b></label><input class = "inp" type = "text" name = "fName" placeholder = "Adam">
<label class = "form">Feedback about the site: <b class = "red">*</b></label>
<textarea class = "area"rows = "5" cols = "50" name = "feedback" placeholder="Enter your comments..."></textarea>


<p><label class = "lbl">Surname: </label><input class = "inp" type = "text" name = "sName" placeholder = "Richardson"></p>
<p><label class = "lbl">Email: </label><input class = "inp" type = "email" name = "eMail" placeholder = "gqfc1@hotmail.com"></p>

<p><label class = "lbl">Rate the website: <b class = "red">*</b></label></p>
<input type = "radio" name = "rating" value = "terrible"> Terrible
<input type = "radio" name = "rating" value = "poor"> Poor
<input type = "radio" name = "rating" value = "adequate"> Adequate
<input type = "radio" name = "rating" value = "good"> Good
<input type = "radio" name = "rating" value = "excellent"> Excellent
<p><input type = "button" name = "input" value = "Submit" class = "btn"></p>
</div>

</form>
```

CSS

```
.red{
    color: #ff0000;
}
.inp{
    padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;
}

.lbl{
    padding: 0 20px 0 150px;
    padding-right:20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 220px;
    float:left;
}
.formBkg{
    background-color: #696969;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
}
.form{
    padding: 0 700px 0 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 220px;
    float:right;
}
.area{
    float:center;
}

.btn{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Could you post a screeshot of what you're aiming for and what you're getting?

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/2uz4d5g/9 sorry I'm working away from home and my devices are messing up... But this is roughly the idea...

Answer (score 0):

set height to `<textarea>` and same line-height to `<label>`

**CSS**

```
.area{
  height:100px;
}
.form{
  line-height:100px;
}
```

> this will vertically align label in center